# R: Merge two dataframes with string in different order

Tags: r

I have two data frames and I need to join them, but the column to use for the join is different. The written text is the same but in a different order. Example of what I mean:

- in a dataframe: "try hello zeta"
- in the other: "hello zeta try".

How do I merge the two data frames using this column with R? I tried fuzzyjoin, but on every attempt, it tells me: "cannot allocate vector of size 49.6 Gb".

Answer (score 0):

Sort the words in the columns first

```
library(tidyverse)
stringi::stri_extract_all_words(c("try hello zeta")) %>% map_chr(~sort(.) %>% paste(., collapse = " "))
[1] "hello try zeta"
stringi::stri_extract_all_words(c("hello zeta try")) %>% map_chr(~sort(.) %>% paste(., collapse = " "))
[1] "hello try zeta"
```